# Как правильно "провалить" тест в PHPUnit

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Как правильно "провалить" тест? Следующий скрипт работает неверно:

```
require_once "TimeInterval.php";
require_once "PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php";
class TimeIntervalTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @var TimeInterval
     */
    private $interval;
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->interval = new TimeInterval();
    }

    public function testSetDayOfTheMonth()
    {
        // false: empty data
        try {
            $this->interval->setDaysOfTheMonth(array());
            $this->fail();// если дошли до сюда, значит тест провален
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            // попадаем всегда сюда, т.к. либо тестируемый метод кидает исключение,                    //                 либо $this->fail() кидает исключение
        }
    }
}
```

Но все нормально работает, если заменить код на:

```
    try {
        $this->interval->setDaysOfTheMonth(array());
        $this->fail();// если дошли до сюда, значит тест провален
    } catch(_Exception $e) {
    }
```

Собственно вопрос: как правильно провалить тест? Мне кажется, что `catch(_Exception $e)` неверный способ. Правильно ли я использую метод `$this->fail();`?
Или вот так правильно:

```
try {
    $this->interval->setDaysOfTheMonth(array());
    $this->fail();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    $this->fail($e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: > // false: empty data

``setDaysOfTheMonth()`` бросает исключение в этом случае?

Comment: да, setDaysOfTheMonth() бросает исключение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тестировать на исключения в `phpUnit` можно [так](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException), используя аннотации:

```
/**
 * @expectedException        MyException
 * @expectedExceptionCode    1234
 * @expectedExceptionMessage MyMessage
 */
public function testSetDayOfTheMonth()
{
    $this->interval->setDaysOfTheMonth(array());
}
```

Либо вот так, используя [setExpectedException()](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest3.php):

```
public function testSetDayOfTheMonth()
{
    $this->setExpectedException('MyException', 'MyMessage', 1234);
    $this->interval->setDaysOfTheMonth(array());
}
```